# Twig Slimframework base template data

Tags: symfony, twig, slim

so I've been working on a simple website and have a simple question, I guess. I have my base template named `template.html` and I'm using it on every html page I have. My question is, can a base template have a data from a database? Because it isn't being rendered right? For example I have here my 404 page (I'm using slim framework btw).

```
$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('404.html');
});
```

And what is inside looks like this:
[image]

As you can see in the image, there is the part `<!-- Loaded data from the base template.html -->`. Can a base template have a data from a database? If so, how? Thank you!

Comment: Creating a twig extension is probably your best bet: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Comment: Hi @cerad, I am getting an undefined variable $loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inheritance](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html).

### Simple method

Your route definition:

```
<?php

/**
 * Not found.
 */
$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
    //Your amazing business to get data
    $books = array(
        "The Hobbit",
        "Leaf by Niggle",
        "The Lay of Aotrou and Itroun",
        "Farmer Giles of Ham",
        "The Homecoming of Beorhtnoth Beorhthelm's Son"
    );
    $app->render('404.html', array(
        'books' => $books
    ));
});
```

Your template.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}
                {% block books %}
                    <h3>My magic books</h3>
                    <ul class="books">
                        {% for book in books %}
                            <li>{{ book }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endblock %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your 404.html:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}

{% block title %}404{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% block books %}
        <div id="">
            {{ parent() }}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

### Hook method

If you need it everywhere, you could use a hook.

```
$app->hook('slim.before.router', function() use ($app) {
    //Your amazing business to get data
    $books = array(
        "The Hobbit",
        "Leaf by Niggle",
        "The Lay of Aotrou and Itroun",
        "Farmer Giles of Ham",
        "The Homecoming of Beorhtnoth Beorhthelm's Son"
    );
    $app->view()->setData('books', $books);
});

//And let your notFound handler be light
$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('404.html');
});
```

Comment: Hi so I will still keep on repeating the array of books in ever $app?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Is your data necessary in all the routes?

Comment: @FewFlyBy I've improved my answer. Hooks will help you ;)

Comment: So if I will use a hook, the base template will automatically carry the data on every template?

Comment: Yes, if you'll call it within slim routes.

Comment: No, you just need it once.

Comment: Hey again, what if I have some router that won't need that?

Comment: You can check the `$app->request()->getPathInfo()` value and add your data only if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a base template can display a DB content:

you have to retrieve the data you want, render it to specific template to display and then, in your base template, you use the render(controller) method, something like

```
public function xyzAction(){
$data=$this->getDoctrine .... ;
return $this->render('XYZYourBundle:test.html.twig',array('data'=>$data));
}
```

in test.html.twig:

```
{℅ for d in data %}
  // do your stuff
{% endfor ℅}
```

and in where you want to add this to your base template:

```
{{ render(controller('XYZYourBundle:Controller_name:xyz'))}}
```

you can pass arguments to the controller action too, [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) would be helpful.

Comment: Alright will definitely try this and will update you. Thank you!

Comment: Doubtful considering that you gave him a Symfony 2 answer for the Slim framework.  render(controller is not going to get him anywhere.

Comment: @Cerad is correct.. I am using slim framework and twig not symfony. .

Answer (score 0):

In Slim 3 you can use Middleware instead hooks.

BooksMiddleware.php

```
class BooksMiddleware{

     protected $container;

     public function __construct($container) {
         $this->container = $container;
     }

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next){

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
      $stmt = $this->container->db->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $books= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

      $request = $request->withAttribute('books', $books);

      $response = $next($request, $response);
      return $response;
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
$app->get('/home', '\HomeController:home')->add(BooksMiddleware::class);
$app->get('/about', '\AboutController:about')->add(BooksMiddleware::class);
```

HomeController.php

```
class HomeController{

  protected $container;

  public function __construct($container) {
      $this->container = $container;
  }

  public function home($request, $response) {

    return $this->container->view->render($response, 'home.html', [
      'books' => $request->getAttribute('books')
    ]);
  }
```

AboutController.php

```
class AboutController{

  protected $container;

  public function __construct($container) {
      $this->container = $container;
  }

  public function about($request, $response) {

    return $this->container->view->render($response, 'about.html', [
      'books' => $request->getAttribute('books')
    ]);
  }

}
```